# ActivityIndicator is not showing on CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uiactivityindicatorview

I want to present activityIndicator animating when I click a collectionviewCell. But it doesn't work, and I could not find out the problem. ActivityIndicator is defined in the Custom collectionViewCell class.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    VMSListCell *cell = [_myCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Inside of main queue with activityindicator");
            cell.activityIndicator.hidden = false;
            [cell.activityIndicator startAnimating];
        });
    NSLog(@"After main queue");
}
```

I am using a custom cell. Logs prints "Inside of main queue with activity indicator", but not "After main queue". And There is no activityIndicator spinning.

Because I will do a http request, after click collectionviewCell, I put activity animating method inside of main queue. I have also tried without main queue, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Is your collectionview not working in mainqueue?, if yes, then how you managed your code?. Here, there is no any need of switching to main queue, as it is already running in main queue. Dont make extra calls which are not required, Still it should work. I think there must be some other problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with this line

```
VMSListCell *cell = [_myCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

In, didselect method, you are taking reusable cell, it will never work, it is fine for cellforItemAtIndexPath method, but it is totally wrongFor didSelectItemAtIndexPath method.

Change above line to this

```
VMSListCell *cell = [_myCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```